# Reading Locked SQLite DB In to Memory

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a project that has some pretty specific requirements, and am running in to a problem with one of them. We have a locked SQLite database. We can't unlock this database, but need to read it (but not write to it), and we cannot create any new files on the filesystem that contain the data from this database. What was suggested is to read the file in to RAM, and then access it from there. I've been trying to find out a way to do this, but this project is on Windows, so it's not going as smoothly as it might otherwise.

What I've been trying to do is read the file in to a bash variable, and then pass that variable to sqlite as the database. This hasn't been working particularly well.

I installed win-bash, but when I do "sqlite3.exe <(cat <<<"$database")" I get a 'syntax error near unexpected token `<('" I checked, and win-bash looks like it's based on an older version of bash. I tried zsh, but it's saying "doesn't look like your system supports FIFOs.". I installed cygwin, which wouldn't really be a good solution anyway (once I figure out how to do this, I need to pass it off to our Qt developers so that they can roll it in to a Qt application) but I was just trying to do a 'proof of concept' - that didn't work either. Sqlite opened just fine, but when i ran ".tables", it said "Error: unable to open database "/dev/fd/63": unable to open database file" So, it looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree, and need to think of some other way to do this.

I guess my questions are, first, is it possible to read a sqlite database in a variable as I was attempting, or am I going down an entirely incorrect path there? Second - if it can't be done that way, is there some way I'm overlooking that might make this possible?

Thanks!